# String padding and slicing to fixed length

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, padding, slice

For some random length array of only 1's and 0's, I need to make it so that the start and end will always be `001` and `100` respectively.

Some examples in string form for readability

```
"11010" => "00110100"
"01010" => "0010100"
"10000" => "00100"
"01100" => "001100"
"11111" => "001111100"
"00100" => "00100"
"00010" => "00100"
"00000" => ""    # cases with no 1's are ignored
```

The code I came up with just shift/unshift push/pops using until

```
def norm(arr)
  (arr.index(1) > 2 ? arr.shift : arr.unshift(0)) until arr.index(1) == 2
  (arr.rindex(1) > arr.length-3 ? arr.push(0) : arr.pop) until arr.rindex(1) == arr.length-3
  arr
end
```

Is there a better(sort of?) way to do it with padding, slicing, etc.?

Comment: I'd recommend waiting longer than 27 minutes before selecting an answer. Often times the best answers take a while to be researched and developed .

Comment: Don't you think it's a bit early to select an answer? I'm revising mine, @theTinMan just posted one and others may well be working on answers as well.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "array of only 1's and 0's" but then show strings. Your code implies your passing in arrays also, but the discrepancy is confusing. Please edit your question making this clear.

Comment: Should I format the examples as arrays? `[1,1,0,0,1,0] => [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]`

Would that be more clear than `110010 => 001100100`

Comment: You must **not** substantially change your question midstream, as it renders comments and answers puzzling and meaningless, and might even result in perfectly good answers to be downvoted. Moreover, you've made it worse switching to "integers" because the integer `001` is the same as `1`, which makes the question nonsense.  You should edit and "roll-back" your question to the strings. Yes, you are new to SO, but don't you think you should have done a bit of investigation before posting a question? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help) is a place to start.

Comment: Ok. I will rollback to strings

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore any `0` before first `1` and after last `1`. So,

```
def norm(arr)
  if arr.include?('1')
    ['0', '0'] + arr.slice(arr.index('1')..arr.rindex('1')) + ['0', '0']
  else
    []
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to do anything sophisticated, I'd do this:

```
[
  "11010", # => "00110100"
  "01010", # => "0010100"
  "10000", # => "00100"
  "01100", # => "001100"
  "11111", # => "001111100"
  "00100", # => "00100"
  "00010", # => "00100"
  "00000", # => ""    # cases with no 1's are ignored
].each do |s|
  if s['1']
    s[/^0*1/] = '001'
    s[/10*$/] = '100'
  end
  puts s
end
```

Running it results in:

```
# >> 00110100
# >> 0010100
# >> 00100
# >> 001100
# >> 001111100
# >> 00100
# >> 00100
# >> 00000
```

This works by first checking to see if the string contains `1`. If it does the code replaces any number of leading `0`s and a `1` with `001`, then replacing a trailing `1` followed by any number of `0`s with `100`.

Comment: Would regex be faster than slicing based on index and rindex?

Comment: Anchored regex are very fast. Write some benchmarks and test.

Comment: That makes sense. I will test it later.

Comment: Oh. These start out in array form as integers.I was just using strings for readability. Edited question.

Comment: It's very important to provide minimal, exact input data. You can tell that you've caused confusion by not doing that.

Comment: Excellent, sn! Your answer also showed me that I had misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regex:

```
r = /
    \A0*   # match beginning of the string followed by zero or more zeroes
    (?=1)  # match 1 in a positive lookahead
    |      # or
    (?<=1) # match 1 in a positive lookbehind
    0*\z   # match zero of more zero's followed by the end of string
    /x     # regex "extended" or "free spacing" mode 

arr = %w| 11010 01010 10000 01100 11111 00100 00010 00000 |
  #=> ["11010", "01010", "10000", "01100", "11111", "00100", "00010", "00000"] 

arr.each { |s| puts "#{s} -> #{ s.gsub(r,'00') }" }
# 11010 -> 00110100
# 01010 -> 0010100
# 10000 -> 00100
# 01100 -> 001100
# 11111 -> 001111100
# 00100 -> 00100
# 00010 -> 00100
# 00000 -> 00000
```